# How to create an EAttribute that has type of an EClass

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-emf

I observed the following problem. In my EMF model I have EClass and I would like to add to another EClass an EAttribute that has type previously defined EClass

```
EClass Type1 {} 
EClass Type2 {
   Type1 attribute
}
```

If user creates POJO. He can write something like this

```
public class C1 {}
public class C2 {
  private C1 c1;
}
```

In case I try add EAttribute using core model editor the list of available types limited by standard EType (EString, EInt etc.). And I cannot setup type of EAttribute which type is equal previously defined EClass.

Is it standard limitation of EMF?

In view where property of atrribute can be edited there are two fields

- EType - contains only default ecore type (EString, EInt etc)
- EAttribyteType - but this field is disable

Comment: I received clear answer on EMF Forum https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1089698/

Comment: It's a good idea to post an answer to your own question if you find a solution for it. Links to external resources can become invalid over time. Also, other people might find your answer interesting and upvote it! Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply use EReference instead of EAttribute.